# Google maps marker not displaying if a field in infoWindowContent is empty

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, laravel, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps embedded into my website that displays Travel Flyers markers that people created. Inside the google maps infoWindowContent, I display the travel flyers title and the travel flyers banner photo.
Like this:
[image: Google Maps]

But when a user decides not to upload a travel flyer banner photo, the the marker on google maps goes away because the banner photo is empty.
Here is the short code for the infoWindowContent:

```html
var infoWindowContent = [
        @foreach($flyer as $flyers)
               [
                   '<div class="info_content">' +
                        '<a href="{{ $flyers->title }}">' +
                            '<img class="ui top aligned small image" src="/travel/{{ $flyers->thumbnail_path }}" alt="Test">' +
                             '<h5>{{ $flyers->title }}</h5>' +
                        '</a>' +
                   '</div>'
               ],
        @endforeach
];
```

How do I make it so that even if there is no travel flyer banner photo to display, the marker still displays on the map?

*********** EDIT *******************
I tried this:

```html
@foreach($flyer as $flyers)
    @if(empty($flyers->thumbnail_path))
       var image = '<img class="ui top aligned small image" src="/travel/src/public/css/01.jpg" alt="Test">';
    @else
       var image = '<img class="ui top aligned small image" src="/travel/{{ $flyers->thumbnail_path }}" alt="Test">';
    @endif
 @endforeach


                var infoWindowContent = [
                        @foreach($flyer as $flyers)
                        [
                            '<div class="info_content">' +
                                '<a href="{{ $flyers->title }}">' +
                                    image +
                                    '<h5>{{ $flyers->title }}</h5>' +
                                '</a>' +
                            '</div>'
                        ],
                    @endforeach
                ];
```

But it still returns only the photos that exist, and does not displayy the marker if no banner image. I also tried: but no luck.

```html
 @if(file_exists($flyers->thumbnail_path))

 @if(file_exists(public_path($flyers->thumbnail_path)))

 @if($flyers->thumbnail_path === '') 

 @if(isset($flyers->thumbnail_path))
```

Comment: One quick solution that comes to mind is some sort of error handling. You should first check if the data you want to inject in the infoWindow exists, if it does then you display it like you are already doing, if not then you should create a different content for the infoWindow. This is just an idea for a possible approach, it is good practice though to keep in mind the use-cases where data is not properly retrieved and make your app behave properly.

Comment: check my edit on top

Answer (score 1):

I don't know laravel but you cant test if the image is set and then prepare a proper string ... somthings like this  (in  pseudo code)

```
   var infoWindowContent = [
    @foreach($flyer as $flyers)
          // test if image is set and prepare a proper string 
          if(isset($flyers->thumbnail_path )){
            echo $my_image = '<img class="ui top aligned small image" src="/travel/{{ $flyers->thumbnail_path }}" alt="Test">';
          } else {
            $my_image = '';
          }

           [
               '<div class="info_content">' +
                    '<a href="{{ $flyers->title }}">' +
                        {{$my_image}} +  // add the per image code (empty html string  for no image)
                         '<h5>{{ $flyers->title }}</h5>' +
                    '</a>' +
               '</div>'
           ],
    @endforeach
```

];

Comment: I suggest you if the image don't exist of set the no html code for this part of string  ... eg: if not exist  var image = '';

Comment: changed it same result

Comment: do u have TeamViewer, maybe u can help me out that way?

Comment: Show me the resulting html for the flyer non functionig e and one of functioning code